# how to rotate an image back and forth in android without using animation

Tags: android

i want to create a car dashboard on android.Actually i am created already this application.But that is based on animation and it is working nicely.Now here i want to add two button(up and down).when i am clicking up the hand have to move 10 degree up.Again click up button means the hand have to move 10 degree up from the current position, and when i am clicking down means it have to come down by 10 degree. i cant do this by a single button in animation.in animation i want to create more button and each button i want to create different animation. This is very complex. please somebody help me to do this.Here i am adding my code

```
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
     import android.graphics.Matrix;
     import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.MotionEvent;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
     import android.view.animation.Animation;
     import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.ImageView;

     public class dash1 extends Activity {
      ImageView img,img1;
  Animation an,an1,an2,an3;Button bt,bt2,bt3,bt4;
         /** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.minute);
    final int w= bmp.getWidth();
    final int h= bmp.getHeight();
    final Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(180);
    Bitmap rtd = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mat, true);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rtd);
    img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
    an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim);
    an1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim1);
    an2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim2);
    an3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim3);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    bt3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    bt4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button04);    

            bt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    an.setFillAfter(true);
                    img.startAnimation(an);


                    return false;
                }
            });
            bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    img.startAnimation(an1);
                }
            });
            bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    an2.setFillAfter(true);
                    img.startAnimation(an2);

                }
            });
            bt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    an3.setFillAfter(true);
                    img.startAnimation(an3);
                }
            });
}


}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to see an animation but you want to have it done without using the animation api or do you just want to display an image rotate once by x degrees?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have everything you need. You just need to change the rotation on the matrix by 10 degrees and apply that to the image you use for your ImageView. As you already rotate the image with 180° you should be familiar with what you need to rotate again 10 degrees...

Sample code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mat.postRotate(10); // or -10 degree
    Bitmap rtd = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mat, true);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rtd);
    img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
}
```

Comment: when i am using that we cant see the movement.Then Why i am using this code here means the original hand image is showing the direction up.This image i placed on another dashboard gauge image. In that the reading start from down. Thats why i am using that code for keep the starting position of hand image down....

Comment: sorry but I have no idea what you are talking about! If you want to handle simple animation on the UI with visible animation, use Animations! Another possibility is to use a SurfaceView and write your own animation there.